# The ability to apply multiple formats to cell with xlwt / openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, openpyxl

I plan to use one of 2 libraries below to output excel file in python:

1. xlwt ( http://www.python-excel.org/ )
2. openpyxl ( http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/ )

I tried the first one, most of things seem to be fine but one issue, unfortunately it may not support the ability to apply multiple formats to cell. (see http://groups.google.com/group/python-excel/browse_thread/thread/11c24606d9b2914d)

Is it true?

If yes, does anybody know how to solve it?

E.g it cannot make some words bold, others regular or different font.

The photo below is the example of what I wanna do. You can see Peter in bold and Fernando in regular text style.

[image: Example]

Comment: All you asked about was `xlwt`. What is your question about `openpyxl`?

Comment: I didn't try openpyxl but I haven't found any articles talking about this problem - multiple formats in one cell.

Comment: Seems like much time has passed since this question was answered. I wonder whether current version of openpyxl supports "rich text" in cells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The svn versions of both `xlrd` and `xlwt` have support for "rich text", which is MS jargon for what you want.

Comment: Update: You can get released versions of xlrd and xlwt from PyPI now ... http://pypi.python.org/pypi/packagename

Answer (score 0):

I have another answer which explains how to apply many formatting styles using openpyxl...

[Setting styles in Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440284/setting-styles-in-openpyxl/8441753)

Comment: Dear Mike, thanks for your answer but that's not what I need. I edited my question, added an example picture.