# openpyxl change one word's color in the same cell

Tags: colors, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to write some data to excel sheet. In my script, I need to append data to the same cell and highlight with different color for the new added data. Currently, I tried below but it turns out all the data's color will change at once. Is there any way to change one word's color in the same cell?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.styles import colors
book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "11111"
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).font = Font(color=colors.GREEN)
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value += " 12345"
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).font = Font(color=colors.RED)
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value += " 22222"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ability to apply multiple formats to cell with xlwt / openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429014/the-ability-to-apply-multiple-formats-to-cell-with-xlwt-openpyxl)

Comment: I look at the solution in The ability to apply multiple formats to cell with xlwt / openpyxl. It looks like openpyxl is not able to achieve what I want.I will try xlwt.

Comment: Here's the bug in openpyxl: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/9/add-support-for-rich-text

Answer (score 3):

`xlswriter` may help you.

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('rich_text.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold_red = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'color': 'red'})
worksheet.write_rich_string('A1',
                            'hello ',
                            bold_red, 'this is bold_red', # style
                            ' and default string')
workbook.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately not possible with openpyxl. You'll have to use `xlwt` (for the legacy Excel format) or `xlsxwriter` (for the current Excel format).

See https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1503 for confirmation that openpyxl does not (and likely will never) support this functionality.

For more information on `xlwt` see https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/.

For more information on `xlsxwriter` see https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/.

Comment: And dont forget Xlwings has also been able to do this using its character class. Openpyxl introduced support for this in 3.1

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question, but I had a similar issue and was able to find a way to accomplish my goal using examples from the openpyxl documentation at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rich_text.html. Note for the code to work, you might need to update to the newest version of openpyxl.

```
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.cell.text import InlineFont 
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText

red = InlineFont(color='00FF0000')
green = InlineFont(color='00008000')
book = openpyxl.load_workbook("rich_text.xlsx")
sheet = book.active
rich_text_cell = CellRichText()
rich_text_cell.append('11111')
rich_text_cell.append(TextBlock(green, '12345'))
rich_text_cell.append(TextBlock(red, '22222'))
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = rich_text_cell
book.save('rich_text.xlsx')
```

Comment: Yes, this only became available officially around version 3.1