# Writing only part of the text in a cell as bold?

Tags: python, openpyxl

i am writing / changing a cell-value in an existing excel-sheet using openpyxl and formating the cell as bold using the following code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("try.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.active
worksheet['C1'] = "this is some text is use"
bold_font = Font(bold=True)
worksheet['C1'].font = bold_font
workbook.save("try.xlsx")
workbook.close()
```

Now i want to format only the first word "is" and "text" in the cell as bold - rest should stay as normal font. How can i do this using openpyxl=

Comment: Check this out, [partial color change of text in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252782/openpyxl-how-to-colour-word-not-whole-cell/75919851#75919851)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible now to bold inline text in the excel sheet cell using OpenPyXL.

Here is the link, [Working with Rich Text](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rich_text.html)

All you need is Rich Text object, all inline font style is achievable with this feature, as per official documentation.

> Rich Text objects can contain a mix of unformatted text and TextBlock
> objects that contains an **InlineFont style** and a the text which is to
> be formatted like this. The result is a CellRichText object.

Support for this feature started from [Version 3.1.0(2023-01-31)](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#id7)

Here is an example,

```
from openpyxl.cell.text import InlineFont
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText

rich_string1 = CellRichText(
    'This is a test ',
    TextBlock(InlineFont(b=True), 'xxx'),
    'yyy'
)
```

Output of the above code -

> This is a test **xxx**yyy

Comment: Thx - works great!