# Retrieving full rich-text data from a cell (multiple font color / styles within cell)

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets-api, xlsx, xls

`openpyxl` can only read and write **one** font color per cell

`xlwriter` supports multiple font colors but only serves for writing and not reading.

`xlwt` is only for writing too.

`xlwings` doesn't support rich text according to their docs.

`xlrd` apparently supports reading "rich text" data from a cell according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429014/the-ability-to-apply-multiple-formats-to-cell-with-xlwt-openpyxl/8488111#8488111), but I'm unable to locate the appropriate method in their API spec and there is no article in their [documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io) dealing with this AFAIK.

And to top it all of, the project is [unmaintained](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd#xlrd) and avises to use `openpyxl`.

It seems I'm at a dead end.

Do you know if it is at all possible to retrieve, in python, the **full** data from such a cell :

[image: rich-text formatted cell]

in particular the full style data, i.e. the different colors and formatting (bold, etc..) used along the cell string.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

PS: If you know how to do it with a google sheet through the Google Sheet API instead, that can also work for me. (Or even in `.odt` format)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I need to find the text spans in red color in some rich-text cells. After diving into the source code of openpyxl (v3.0.9), I found it [do parse the rich-text tags](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/064db970d8dc2dc9178984097958607121feaedb/openpyxl/cell/text.py#L152) but the formats are [stripped by the reader](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/064db970d8dc2dc9178984097958607121feaedb/openpyxl/reader/strings.py#L17) as the [`content`](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/064db970d8dc2dc9178984097958607121feaedb/openpyxl/cell/text.py#L174) property of `Text` object is used in the [`read_string_table`](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/064db970d8dc2dc9178984097958607121feaedb/openpyxl/reader/strings.py#L9) function.

So, I wrote a simple patch script to override the `read_string_table` function such that the raw `Text` object is returned when formatted text exists. The modified `read_string_table` function is as below.

```
def read_string_table(xml_source):
    """Read in all shared strings in the table.
    If a shared string has formatted snippets, the raw Text object is appended to the returned list.
    Otherwise, only the plain text content of the shared string is appended to the list.
    """
    strings = []
    STRING_TAG = '{%s}si' % SHEET_MAIN_NS
    for _, node in iterparse(xml_source):
        if node.tag == STRING_TAG:
            text_obj = Text.from_tree(node)
            if text_obj.formatted:
                text = text_obj  # return raw Text object
            else:  # original processing
                text = text_obj.content
                text = text.replace('x005F_', '')
            node.clear()
            strings.append(text)
    return strings
```

The full patch script is available [here](https://gist.github.com/tjumyk/3b6fe1741d6a402e22fe36e3ab5bd818). You need to import it and call the `patch_read_string_table` function before importing any openpyxl modules directly. After applying this patch, the `value` of a Rich-text cell will be a `Text` object that contains all the style information you want.

Depending on your use case, this might not be the best solution, but it shows you where the formats are stripped and how you may get them back. I hope that a more elegant solution can be proposed and eventually merged into the official code in the future.

Comment: How can we extract portions of the cell text that are bold using this method?

Comment: rich text is fully supported, see https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rich_text.html